# How can I enhance the ZigZag-Indicator in MetaTrader Terminal 5 to include bars and points for visualizing ranges?

Tags: mql4, indicator, mql5, metatrader5, meta-query

**Title :**
Enhancing ZigZag-Indicator in MetaTrader Terminal 5: Visualizing Range with Bars and Points

**Question :**
I'm looking to enhance the functionality of the ZigZag indicator in MetaTrader Terminal 5 by visualizing the range between the highest and lowest points using bars and points. Currently, the indicator only plots lines connecting the significant swing highs and lows. However, I believe that incorporating bars and points would offer a more comprehensive view of the indicator's behavior and potentially identify additional trading opportunities.

I have successfully combined the addition of `BarCountBuffer[]` and `PointCountBuffer[]` to the existing code. These buffers are used to store the number of bars and points since the last extreme point in the ZigZag-indicator.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                Leandre Hirwa.mq5 |
//|                                                                  |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+


#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 5
#property indicator_plots   3
//--- plot ZigZag
#property indicator_label1  "ZigZag"
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_SECTION
#property indicator_color1  clrRed
#property indicator_style1  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width1  1
//--- plot High points
#property indicator_label2  "High Points"
#property indicator_type2   DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_color2  clrGreen
#property indicator_style2  STYLE_ARROWUP
//--- plot Low points
#property indicator_label3  "Low Points"
#property indicator_type3   DRAW_ARROW
#property indicator_color3  clrRed
#property indicator_style3  STYLE_ARROWDOWN
//--- input parameters
input int InpDepth    = 12;  // Depth
input int InpDeviation= 5;   // Deviation
input int InpBackstep = 3;   // Back Step
//--- indicator buffers
double    ZigZagBuffer[];      // main buffer
double    HighMapBuffer[];     // ZigZag high extremes (peaks)
double    LowMapBuffer[];      // ZigZag low extremes (bottoms)
double    BarCountBuffer[];    // number of bars since last extreme point
double    PointCountBuffer[];  // number of points since last extreme point

int       ExtRecalc=3;         // number of last extremes for recalculation

enum EnSearchMode
{
   Extremum=0, // searching for the first extremum
   Peak=1,     // searching for the next ZigZag peak
   Bottom=-1   // searching for the next ZigZag bottom
};
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnInit()
{
   //--- indicator buffers mapping
   SetIndexBuffer(0,ZigZagBuffer,INDICATOR_DATA);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,HighMapBuffer,INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
   SetIndexBuffer(2,LowMapBuffer,INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
   SetIndexBuffer(3,BarCountBuffer,INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
   SetIndexBuffer(4,PointCountBuffer,INDICATOR_CALCULATIONS);
   //--- set short name and digits
   string short_name=StringFormat("ZigZag(%d,%d,%d)",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep);
   IndicatorSetString(INDICATOR_SHORTNAME,short_name);
   PlotIndexSetString(0,PLOT_LABEL,short_name);
   IndicatorSetInteger(INDICATOR_DIGITS,_Digits);
   //--- set an empty value
   PlotIndexSetDouble(0,PLOT_EMPTY_VALUE,0.0);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| ZigZag calculation                                               |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
               
{
   if(rates_total<100)
      return(0);
   //---
   int    i=0;
   int    start=0,extreme_counter=0,extreme_search=Extremum;
   int    shift=0,back=0,last_high_pos=0,last_low_pos=0;
   double val=0,res=0;
   double curlow=0,curhigh=0,last_high=0,last_low=0;
   //--- initializing
   if(prev_calculated==0)
   {
      ArrayInitialize(ZigZagBuffer,0.0);
      ArrayInitialize(HighMapBuffer,0.0);
      ArrayInitialize(LowMapBuffer,0.0);
      ArrayInitialize(BarCountBuffer,0.0);
      ArrayInitialize(PointCountBuffer,0.0);
      start=InpDepth;
   }
   //--- ZigZag was already calculated before
   if(prev_calculated>0)
   {
      i=rates_total-1;
      //--- searching for the third extremum from the last uncompleted bar
      while(extreme_counter<ExtRecalc && i>rates_total-100)
      {
         res=ZigZagBuffer[i];
         if(res!=0.0)
            extreme_counter++;
         i--;
      }
      i++;
      start=i;
      //--- what type of extremum we search for
      if(LowMapBuffer[i]!=0.0)
      {
         curlow=LowMapBuffer[i];
         extreme_search=Peak;
      }
      else
      {
         curhigh=HighMapBuffer[i];
         extreme_search=Bottom;
      }
      //--- clear indicator values
      for(i=start+1; i<rates_total && !IsStopped(); i++)
      {
         ZigZagBuffer[i] =0.0;
         LowMapBuffer[i] =0.0;
         HighMapBuffer[i]=0.0;
         BarCountBuffer[i] = 0.0;
         PointCountBuffer[i] = 0.0;
      }
   }
   //--- searching for high and low extremes
   for(shift=start; shift<rates_total && !IsStopped(); shift++)
   {
      //--- low
      val=low[Lowest(low,InpDepth,shift)];
      if(val==last_low)
         val=0.0;
      else
      {
         last_low=val;
         if((low[shift]-val)>InpDeviation*_Point)
            val=0.0;
         else
         {
            for(back=1; back<=InpBackstep; back++)
            {
               res=LowMapBuffer[shift-back];
               if((res!=0) && (res>val))
                  LowMapBuffer[shift-back]=0.0;
            }
         }
      }
      if(low[shift]==val)
         LowMapBuffer[shift]=val;
      else
         LowMapBuffer[shift]=0.0;
      //--- high
      val=high[Highest(high,InpDepth,shift)];
      if(val==last_high)
         val=0.0;
      else
      {
         last_high=val;
         if((val-high[shift])>InpDeviation*_Point)
            val=0.0;
         else
         {
            for(back=1; back<=InpBackstep; back++)
            {
               res=HighMapBuffer[shift-back];
               if((res!=0) && (res<val))
                  HighMapBuffer[shift-back]=0.0;
            }
         }
      }
      if(high[shift]==val)
         HighMapBuffer[shift]=val;
      else
         HighMapBuffer[shift]=0.0;
   }
   //--- set last values
   if(extreme_search==0) // undefined values
   {
      last_low=0.0;
      last_high=0.0;
   }
   else
   {
      last_low=curlow;
      last_high=curhigh;
   }
   //--- final selection of extreme points for ZigZag
   for(shift=start; shift<rates_total && !IsStopped(); shift++)
   {
      res=0.0;
      switch(extreme_search)
      {
         case Extremum:
            if(last_low==0.0 && last_high==0.0)
            {
               if(HighMapBuffer[shift]!=0)
               {
                  last_high=high[shift];
                  last_high_pos=shift;
                  extreme_search=Bottom;
                  ZigZagBuffer[shift]=last_high;
                  res=1;
               }
               if(LowMapBuffer[shift]!=0.0)
               {
                  last_low=low[shift];
                  last_low_pos=shift;
                  extreme_search=Peak;
                  ZigZagBuffer[shift]=last_low;
                  res=1;
               }
            }
            break;
         case Peak:
            if(LowMapBuffer[shift]!=0.0 && LowMapBuffer[shift]<last_low && HighMapBuffer[shift]==0.0)
            {
               ZigZagBuffer[last_low_pos]=0.0;
               last_low_pos=shift;
               last_low=LowMapBuffer[shift];
               ZigZagBuffer[shift]=last_low;
               res=1;
            }
            if(HighMapBuffer[shift]!=0.0 && LowMapBuffer[shift]==0.0)
            {
               last_high=HighMapBuffer[shift];
               last_high_pos=shift;
               ZigZagBuffer[shift]=last_high;
               extreme_search=Bottom;
               res=1;
            }
            break;
         case Bottom:
            if(HighMapBuffer[shift]!=0.0 && HighMapBuffer[shift]>last_high && LowMapBuffer[shift]==0.0)
            {
               ZigZagBuffer[last_high_pos]=0.0;
               last_high_pos=shift;
               last_high=HighMapBuffer[shift];
               ZigZagBuffer[shift]=last_high;
            }
            if(LowMapBuffer[shift]!=0.0 && HighMapBuffer[shift]==0.0)
            {
               last_low=LowMapBuffer[shift];
               last_low_pos=shift;
               ZigZagBuffer[shift]=last_low;
               extreme_search=Peak;
            }
            break;
         default:
            return(rates_total);
      }
      //--- calculate bar and point counts
      if (res == 1)
      {
         if (extreme_search == Peak)
            BarCountBuffer[shift] = BarCountBuffer[shift - 1] + 1;
         else if (extreme_search == Bottom)
            BarCountBuffer[shift] = BarCountBuffer[shift - 1];
         if (BarCountBuffer[shift] > 0)
            PointCountBuffer[shift] = PointCountBuffer[shift - 1] + MathAbs(ZigZagBuffer[shift] - ZigZagBuffer[shift - 1]);
      }
      else
      {
         BarCountBuffer[shift] = BarCountBuffer[shift - 1];
         PointCountBuffer[shift] = PointCountBuffer[shift - 1];
      }
   }
   //--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
   return(rates_total);
}
```

Anybody can access my codes from the following Google doc

[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mzT8jJPmV9tTXzz8NM837F5aSJhMMnQ10W0HkSgTSTI/edit?usp=sharing)